# Wagtail: How to configure ImageChooserPanel to paginate with more images per page?

Tags: wagtail

By default **ImageChooserPanel** paginates with **20** images per page. Is it possible to visualize more images per page (40 for example)?.

I think than ImageChooserPanel has no configuration options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, the number of images for the image chooser pagination [is hardcoded to 12](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/3b44b354e3e705b07646b9345df2cd7f6e144855/wagtail/wagtailimages/views/chooser.py#L82) (I'm not sure why you say 20), but I think it's a good idea to make page size configurable.

Feel free to create [a new issue or submit a pull request](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md) into the [Wagtail](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/) repository.

---

**UPD 23rd of May, 2017**

There are few cases of pagination for images:

- Image chooser modal window (`ImageChooserPanel` and `ImageChooserBlock` classes). Both image choosers use the [`wagtail.wagtailimages.views.chooser.chooser`](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/3b44b354e3e705b07646b9345df2cd7f6e144855/wagtail/wagtailimages/views/chooser.py#L82) view that returns [a page with 12 images](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/3b44b354e3e705b07646b9345df2cd7f6e144855/wagtail/wagtailimages/views/chooser.py#L82). I thought that the question was about this case, because you have mentioned the `ImageChooserPanel` class in the initial question.
- Images listing view ([`wagtail.wagtailimages.views.images.index`](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/3b44b354e3e705b07646b9345df2cd7f6e144855/wagtail/wagtailimages/views/images.py#L59)). It uses the default pagination value (20 items, at the moment) which is specified in the [`wagtail.utils.pagination.paginate`](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/master/wagtail/utils/pagination.py#L11) utility function.

Comment: wagtailimages app shows 20 images per page. I think it's harcoded here  https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/master/wagtail/utils/pagination.py#L11

Comment: Ah, I thought that your questions was about the image chooser modal windows, not about the listing (Admin UI > Images). I've added some additional info into my answer.